# Showing unable to locate libmysql-java after sudo apt-get install libmysql-java statement

Tags: apt, package-management, java, mysql

Even I have tried java-mysql but also showing this
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package java-mysql

libmysql-java--

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmysql-java

I have Just downloaded the package and now I don't know where to place it.